# VBA: Assign Worksheet with current date to an object

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

A piece of my macro adds a new worksheet with the current date but when I want to assign the worksheet to an object it doesn't work. I get a

> run time error 9

```
Dim shA As Worksheet
Set shA = Worksheets(Date)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What format is your date ?

Comment: The format is: DD.MM.YYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `Date` to a `String` format, depending on the format of your date.

```
Dim shA As Worksheet
Set shA = Worksheets(Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your computer date is in format `DD.MM.YYYY`, if you are looking to change the tab name of the worksheet, then it is like this:

`ActiveSheet.name = Date()`

or

`shA.Name = Date()`

Thus, you will get this:

[image]